# wireguard + ufw = unable to limit access to specific port

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, ufw

So I'm trying to limit access to port 5432 (postgres) by using **ufw** and unable to do so. The connection is allowed still

```sh
sudo ufw deny 5432/tcp
sudo ufw route deny in on wg0 from 10.0.10.2
```

```sh
root@vpn-prod:/home/ubuntu# ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (medium)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
51820/udp                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
51820/udp (v6)             ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             

5432/tcp                   DENY OUT    Anywhere                  
5432/tcp (v6)              DENY OUT    Anywhere (v6)             

Anywhere                   DENY FWD    10.0.10.2 on wg0
```

so I'm connect from wireguard client to server. From there there is internal IP `10.120.0.149` that runs postgres.

Below is tcpdump on the server:

```sh
root@vpn-prod:/var/log# sudo tcpdump -envi wg0: net 10.120.0.0/16
tcpdump: listening on wg0:, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
21:36:18.948194 ip: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 23874, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    10.0.10.2.37056 > 10.120.0.149.5432: Flags [S], cksum 0xd974 (correct), seq 3860575203, win 64860, options [mss 1380,sackOK,TS val 2547481248 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
21:36:18.948370 ip: (tos 0x0, ttl 254, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    10.120.0.149.5432 > 10.0.10.2.37056: Flags [S.], cksum 0x7eb2 (correct), seq 888276479, ack 3860575204, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2284266370 ecr 2547481248,nop,wscale 10], length 0
21:36:18.979477 ip: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 23875, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    10.0.10.2.37056 > 10.120.0.149.5432: Flags [.], cksum 0x1c88 (correct), ack 1, win 507, options [nop,nop,TS val 2547481279 ecr 2284266370], length 0
21:36:18.986946 ip: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 23876, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    10.0.10.2.37056 > 10.120.0.149.5432: Flags [P.], cksum 0x0167 (correct), seq 1:9, ack 1, win 507, options [nop,nop,TS val 2547481287 ecr 2284266370], length 8
21:36:18.987075 ip: (tos 0x0, ttl 254, id 35821, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    10.120.0.149.5432 > 10.0.10.2.37056: Flags [.], cksum 0x1e30 (correct), ack 9, win 29, options [nop,nop,TS val 2284266408 ecr 2547481287], length 0
```

I see nothing in ufw.log for ips: 10.0.10.2 (wireguard peer) or 10.120.0.149 (postgres)
It looks like ufw is doing nothing for traffic on wg0 interface

```sh
root@vpn-prod:/var/log# ip -brief a s
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 ::1/128 
ens5             UP             10.120.101.242/22 fe80::30:deff:feb2:dc11/64 
wg0              UNKNOWN        10.0.10.1/32

root@vpn-prod:/var/log# wg show
interface: wg0
  public key: HIDDEN
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 51820

peer: HIDDEN....=
  preshared key: (hidden)
  endpoint: 71.200.111.100:51820
  allowed ips: 10.0.10.2/32
  latest handshake: 55 seconds ago
  transfer: 56.29 KiB received, 143.69 KiB sent
  persistent keepalive: every 25 seconds
```

#### my iptables

```sh
root@vpn-prod:/var/log# iptables -L -n -v
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 6139  581K ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 6139  581K ufw-before-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ufw-after-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ufw-reject-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ufw-track-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  373 39936 ACCEPT     all  --  wg0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  271  125K ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  271  125K ufw-before-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ufw-after-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ufw-reject-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ufw-track-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 4792  999K ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 4792  999K ufw-before-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  188 13856 ufw-after-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  188 13856 ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  188 13856 ufw-reject-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  188 13856 ufw-track-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:137
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:138
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:139
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:445
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
    0     0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   26  2241 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  271  125K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
    0     0 ufw-user-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  262 22619 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 5819  555K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    9   252 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
    9   252 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
   36  2310 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:67 dpt:68
   13  1012 ufw-not-local  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251          udp dpt:5353
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900
   13  1012 ufw-user-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW AUDIT] "

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   37  2751 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW AUDIT] "

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   40  3296 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW AUDIT] "

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  262 22619 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 4342  962K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
  188 13856 ufw-user-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    2    56 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW AUDIT INVALID] "
    2    56 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-not-local (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   13  1012 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
    0     0 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  106  6360 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW
   81  7412 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  wg0    *       10.0.10.2            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:51820

Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5432
root@vpn-prod:/var/log#
```

#### wg0.conf on the server

```sh
root@vpn-prod:/var/log# cat /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf 
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.10.1/32
PrivateKey = HIDDEN

ListenPort = 51820
PostUp = sysctl -w -q net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
PostUp = sysctl -w -q net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
PostUp = iptables -P FORWARD DROP
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens5 -j MASQUERADE
PostUp = ip6tables -P FORWARD DROP
PostUp = ip6tables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostUp = ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens5 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = sysctl -w -q net.ipv4.ip_forward=0
PostDown = sysctl -w -q net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=0
PostDown = iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o ens5 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = ip6tables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
PostDown = ip6tables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
PostDown = ip6tables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o ens5 -j MASQUERADE

[Peer]
# friendly_name = my-desktop
PublicKey = HIDDEN
PresharedKey = HIDDEN
AllowedIPs = 10.0.10.2/32
PersistentKeepalive = 25

root@vpn-prod:/var/log#
```

**I also tried the following, but it didn't work either**:

```sh
ufw route deny in on wg0 to 10.120.0.0/16 from any
ufw route deny to 10.120.0.0/16 from any
ufw route deny in on ens5 to 10.120.0.0/16 from any
```